# How to execute a function after a group components did mount in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Callback `componentDidMount` works perfectly when I am dealing with elements in that component, but I want to execute a function that deals with element of multiple components on a page, after a group of components been mounted. What is the best way I can do that?

Comment: This seems like you are trying to create an antipattern.  What are you actually attempting to **do** that requires triggering events based on mounting conditions spread across the application?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a callback function into each component using `props` that each `componentDidMount` method calls to their parent component, which say, updates a counter in that component's state. When the counter reaches the amount of components you expect to render, execute your function.

In Parent component:

```
....

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextState.childCount >= 4;
}

incrementChildCount() {
  this.setState({ childCount: this.state.childCount + 1 });
}

render() {
   return(
     <div id="container">
        <Child callme={this.incrementChildCount} />
        <Child callme={this.incrementChildCount} />
        <Child callme={this.incrementChildCount} />
        <Child callme={this.incrementChildCount} />
   );
}
```

In Child component:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.callme()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other components are all children, you could define a function for them and assign them a `ref` when instantiating.  Then the parent can execute that function:

```
...
componentDidMount: function() {
  var ret = true;
  var refs = this.refs;
  for (var ref in refs) {
    if (refs.hasOwnProperty(ref)) {
      ret = refs[ref].isValid().success && ret;
    }
  }
  return ret;
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent ref="something" />
      <ChildComponent ref="somethingElse" />
    </div> 
 );
}
```

The child would have something like:

```
...
isValid: function() {
  // this is just an example; i don't know what you want your children to return or do...
  ret = true;
  if (<you conditions here>) {
    ret = false;
  }
  return ret;
},
...
```

Comment: I will add that this is one way of achieving what the OP is describing and that @erik-sn 's answer is also a very good option, too